# pr is truncating output

Tags: text-processing, pr

I have three text files and I want to combine them in one text file on my Linux machine.

Input files:

1_val.txt

```
0x0000000000060b7c02555b80
0x0000000000060b7c026c6580
0x0000000000060b7c0285ff80
```

2_val.txt

```
0x0000000000060b7c0257a180
0x0000000000060b7c026eab80
0x0000000000060b7c02884580
```

3_val.txt

```
2.2734
2.2734
2.2734
```

Expected output:

values.txt

```
0x0000000000060b7c02555b80 0x0000000000060b7c0257a180 2.2734
0x0000000000060b7c026c6580 0x0000000000060b7c026eab80 2.2734
0x0000000000060b7c0285ff80 0x0000000000060b7c02884580 2.2734
```

Output generated: The last three values in the first and second column are missing.

```
0x0000000000060b7c02555 0x0000000000060b7c0257a 2.2734
0x0000000000060b7c026c6 0x0000000000060b7c026ea 2.2734
0x0000000000060b7c0285f 0x0000000000060b7c02884 2.2734
```

The code I used to get this done,

```
pr -m -t 1_val.txt 2_val.txt 3_val.txt > values.txt
```

Comment: Does any file contain CR LF line endings?

Comment: No... just that it begins with 0x0000.... as i mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-J` switch to join the full lines and turn line truncation off.

```
pr -J -m -t 1_val.txt 2_val.txt 3_val.txt > values.txt
```

or set the page width to a large enough value:

```
pr -W80 -m -t 1_val.txt 2_val.txt 3_val.txt > values.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `paste` and specify a space delimiter:

```
paste -d' ' 1_val.txt 2_val.txt 3_val.txt >values.txt
```

The problem is that the `-m` option of `pr` will truncate long lines by default (from `man pr`, emphasis mine):

> -m, --merge
>
> print all files in  parallel,  one  in  each  column,
> **truncate lines**, but join lines of full length with -J

In your case, this was cutting the last few characters of each line from your first file.

Comment: @they actually, it turns out that this is the default behavior of `pr`: it will truncate long lines by default so the OP's result is reproducible using their command and works as expected with `paste`.

Comment: @gogoud that is a great explanation and it worked.